# How to configure code Formatter in Eclipse to add new line after each element in enum?

Tags: java, eclipse, enums, formatting, eclipse-mars

When I format an **enum** using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> in Eclipse It does not add a `new line`  after each element in **enum**. Like this

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    ELEMENT(0),ELEMENT(1);
}
```

But I need a format like this:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    ELEMENT(0),
    ELEMENT(1);
}
```

How can we configure **Formatter** in Eclipse to add **new line**  after each element in **enum**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to `Line Wrapping` in Java Formatter. Expand `'enum' declaration` and choose `Constants`. Select `Wrap all elements, every element on a new line` in `Line wrapping policy` and check `Force split, even if line shorter than maximum line width`. `Apply` and `OK`.